# memset operation on double pointer

Tags: c, pointers, memset, pointer-to-pointer

[Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12705649/how-do-i-do-a-memset-for-a-pointer-to-an-array) is relevant.

For the below representation,

```
  typedef struct List{

    void **array; // array of void*
    int lastItemPosition;
    int size;
  }List;

  #define INITIAL_LIST_SIZE 50
```

`createList` performs as shown below,

```
List *createList(List *list, Op opType){

  List *lptr = (List *)malloc(sizeof(List));

  if(opType == CREATE_NEW_LIST){

    lptr->array = malloc(INITIAL_LIST_SIZE*sizeof(void*));
    lptr->array = memset(lptr->array, NULL, INITIAL_LIST_SIZE*sizeof(void *));
    lptr->lastItemPosition = -1;
    lptr->size = INITIAL_LIST_SIZE;
}
```

Is `memset` performing valid operation on `lptr->array`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code,

```
 memset(lptr->array, NULL, INITIAL_LIST_SIZE*sizeof(void *));
```

is wrong, as the second argument is expected to be an `int`, you're passing a pointer. The conversion is a highly implementation defined behaviour, and in most of the cases, it would invoke UB.

Related, quoting `C11`, chapter §7.19

> `NULL`
>   which expands to an implementation-defined null pointer constant; [...]

and, chapter §6.3.2.3

> An integer constant expression with the value 0, or such an expression **cast to type
>   `void *`, is called a `null pointer constant`.**

So, `NULL` is of pointer type which is not the compatible type to an `int` in any ways.

Comment: `#define NULL 0` in `stddef.h`

Comment: @overexchange show me the same in chapter 7.19, C11.

Comment: `NULL` is only required to have a value zero.   However, it CAN have a pointer type, in which case passing it where an `int` is expected is invalid (and will not compile).

Comment: Am expecting 50(`INITIAL_LIST_SIZE`) pointers to zero using `memset`. Can you confirm? If yes, How is that working internally?

Comment: @overexchange Sorry, confirm what, exactly? First of all, don't use `0` to set a value to a pointer type, as the literal `0`, has a type integer. Use `NULL`, which is more reliable and correct way to initialize a pointer.

Comment: ##1) Is this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1367411/3317808) obsolete wrt initialising zero? To initialise `NULL` to 50 pointers pointed by `lptr->array`, `memset` is not the right choice. Shall I use for-loop ? ##2) Can you confirm, whether lptr->array has set 50(INITIAL_LIST_SIZE) pointers to zero using `memset`?

Answer (score 1):

It's valid on all major platforms, except for one thing: Don't pass `NULL` as the value to set. Remember that the `memset` function operates on the individual *bytes* of the memory, and you should set all the bytes to zero (`0`).

It is however not strictly technically valid. On most major platforms a null pointer is equal to zero. ***But*** it doesn't have to be that. The only fully portable and safe way to do it is through a manual loop where you set each pointer explicitly to `NULL`.

---

And if anyone is interested to know, even if `NULL` is defined as `0` (or `((void *) 0)`) it doesn't matter. The compiler will translate that zero into the platform-specific version of a null pointer, which may be something else than the actual integer zero.

Comment: I kept `NULL` for readability saying that each `void *` in `**array` is `NULL`

Comment: @overexchange That could cause the compiler to emit a warning about conversions from pointer to non-pointer type, depending on the definition of `NULL`.

Comment: Can you enumerate any case where NULL != 0? As far as I understand NULL is not defined by the standard yet NULL == 0 is so ubiquitous that it may as well be.

Comment: @doron `NULL` is defined in the C standard as a compiler-specific null-pointer constant. It's specified in 7.19 (Common definitions <stddef.h>) section 3 of the C11 standard (INCITS+ISO+IEC+9899-2011[2012])